# AngularJS and handling scope refresh after SSE callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm relatively new to both Angular and JS, but please bear with me. I've seen many similar questions, but none of these really seem to answer my question.

I have the following service, which subscribes to a stream of messages containing Twitter messages

```
angular.module('twitterstream.services', [])
    .factory('tweetService', function() {
        var tweets = [];
        var tweetFeed = new EventSource("/feed");
        tweetFeed.addEventListener("message", feedCallback, false);

        return {
            getTweets: getTweets
        };

        function getTweets() {
            return tweets;
        }       

        function feedCallback(message) {
            var tweet = JSON.parse(message.data);
            tweets.push(tweet);
        }
    })
```

In my controller I'm watching the `tweets` property of the service:

```
angular.module('twitterstream.controllers', ['twitterstream.services'])
    .controller('tweetController', ['$scope', 'tweetService', function($scope, tweetService) {
        $scope.tweets = [];

        $scope.$watch(
            function() {
                return tweetService.getTweets();
            },
            function(newVal, oldVal) {
                $scope.tweets = newVal;
            }
        );
    }]);
```

And here's my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/services/services.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body data-ng-app="twitterstream">
    Hello jerks
    <br>
    <div data-ng-controller="tweetController">
      <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="tweet in tweets">
          {{tweet.text}}
        </li>
      </ul>    
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now, here's the problem: `<ul>` is not getting updated.

Just to be clear:

- The Server Sent Events work, I have checked this
- The EventStream callback works as well, the `tweets` in the service are getting updated
- The $watch function works as well, the `tweets` in the controller are getting updated as well

But the UI is not getting updated. However, if I call

```
angular.element($("div")).inheritedData().$scope.$apply();
```

from the developers console, the entire DOM refreshes nicely as expected.

This prompted me to manually insert an $apply call in the controller here:

```
$scope.$watch(
    function() {
        return tweetService.getTweets();
    },
    function(newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.tweets = newVal;
        $scope.$apply();          // <---- Right over here
    }
);
```

But this yields the following error as soon as the application boots:

```
[$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

Most of the examples I've found on SO don't separate the subscription to the EventSource into a service, and just keep everything in a single controller. Of course, I don't have a $scope object to work with in my service, so I can't call $apply in the EventSource callback.

What is the most elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it easily:

```
angular.module('twitterstream', []);

angular.module('twitterstream.services', [])
.factory('tweetService', function() {
   var tweets = [];
   var tweetFeed = new EventSource("/feed");

   // the factory returns a function waiting for a callback that will handle the controller
   return {
       getTweets: function(callback) {
         tweetFeed.addEventListener("message", callback, false);
       }
   }; 
});

angular.module('twitterstream.controllers', ['twitterstream.services'])
.controller('tweetController', ['$scope', 'tweetService', function($scope, tweetService) {
      // the controller will assign the value when 'message' event is ready
      $scope.tweets = tweetService.getTweets(function(response) {
          var tweets = JSON.parse(response.data);
          $scope.tweets = tweets;
      });
}]);
```

I hope this can help you :)

Comment: That does the trick, though I'm guessing the controller should be something more along the lines of $scope.tweets.push(tweet); $scope.$apply();? :-)